# Adding index for the mongodb collection for given query in $and

Tags: mongodb

I am having collection with structure below.In this there are some duplicate contents header name and values.But I need to fetch the exact document.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("573ebc7bbf50112d55c0b763"),
    "topic": "AAA",
    "contents": [{
        "headerName": "Start Year",
        "value": 1995
    }, {
        "headerName": "Program",
        "value": "AAA"
    }]
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("573ebc7bbf50112d55c0b763"),
    "topic": "BBB",
    "contents": [{
        "headerName": "Start Year",
        "value": 1989
    }, {
        "headerName": "Program",
        "value": "BBB"
    }, {
        "headerName": "Likes",
        "value": 51
    }]
}, {
    "_id": ObjectId("573ebc7bbf50112d55c0b763"),
    "topic": "BBB",
    "contents": [{
        "headerName": "Start Year",
        "value": 1989
    }, {
        "headerName": "Program",
        "value": "BBB"
    }]
}
```

I need to fetch the single document using the below query. How can i add index for this.

```
db.collections.find({
    "$and": [{
        "topic": "BBB"
    }, {
        "contents": [{
            "headerName": "Start Year",
            "value": 1989
        }, {
            "headerName": "Program",
            "value": "BBB"
        }]
    }, {
        "contents": {
            "$size": 2
        }
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a compound index on the fields

```
db.collection.createIndex( { topic:1, contents: 1 } )
```

Note that order matters in MongoDB compound indexes, as with any database. If you make an index with "topic" first, Mongo can jump straight to the section of the index with signed topics, then do a bound-scan from contents

After that change your query to this:

```
db.collection.find({
    "topic" : "BBB",        
    "contents.headerName": { "$in": [ "Start Year", "Program" ] },
    "contents.value": { "$in": [ 1989, "BBB" ] },
    "contents": { "$size": 2 }
})
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("573ee720b986a3b71e1e517b"),
    "topic" : "BBB",
    "contents" : [ 
        {
            "headerName" : "Start Year",
            "value" : 1989
        }, 
        {
            "headerName" : "Program",
            "value" : "BBB"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

To see how the index perfoms, run **[`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/method/cursor.explain/)** on the query:

```
db.collection.find({
    "topic" : "BBB",        
    "contents.headerName": { "$in": [ "Start Year", "Program" ] },
    "contents.value": { "$in": [ 1989, "BBB" ] },
    "contents": { "$size": 2 }
}).explain()
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test.collection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "contents" : {
                        "$size" : 2
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "topic" : {
                        "$eq" : "BBB"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "contents.headerName" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            "Program", 
                            "Start Year"
                        ]
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "contents.value" : {
                        "$in" : [ 
                            1989, 
                            "BBB"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "contents" : {
                                "$size" : 2
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "contents.headerName" : {
                                "$in" : [ 
                                    "Program", 
                                    "Start Year"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "contents.value" : {
                                "$in" : [ 
                                    1989, 
                                    "BBB"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "topic" : 1,
                        "contents" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "topic_1_contents_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "topic" : [ 
                            "[\"BBB\", \"BBB\"]"
                        ],
                        "contents" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    }
}
```